# Slow-down encountered for RandomChoice in large lists

Tags: graphs-and-networks, performance-tuning, random

I was wondering if anyone could help me to speed up this code snippet which creates simple (sparse) networks by preferential attachment.

The algorithm adds a vertex and an edge each time interval. Each end of the edge is assigned independantly according to a lottery where vertices have weight $m+k$ where $m$ is constant and $k$ is the vertex degree.

The issue is that while `RandomChoice` performs the lottery mechanism very elegantly and very quickly for $n<10^6$, it does so very slowly for large networks.

```
n = 10^6;
w = Array[0 &, n];
x = Range[n];
m = 1;
g = Table[
  {i, j} = RandomChoice[w[[1 ;; t]] + m -> x[[1 ;; t]], 2];
  w[[{i, j}]]++;
  i <-> j,
{t, 1, n}]
```

Comment: You are recreating a sublist at every iteration and that means it will be, at best, O(n^2) complexity. Most likely better would be to pick two random integers between 1 and `t` and use them as indices.

Comment: Can you explain precisely the properties you want for your graph?  I strongly suspect there are far faster---${\cal O}(n)$---algorithms for what you seek.

Comment: The properties are actually quite easily derived in the limit. In this instance I just want to see the significance of finite-size effects.

Answer (score 8):

Preferential growth with an increasing number of vertices means that older vertices will have far more connections than the newer ones. So we know which vertices will probably be chosen, and we should try to use that in our algorithm. One way to do it is [roulette wheel selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection):

```
randomChoice = Compile[{{list, _Real, 1}}, 
  Module[{acc, i = 1, r1 = 0., r2 = 0., i1 = 1, i2 = 1, res},
   acc = Accumulate[list];
   r1 = RandomReal[{1, Last@acc}];
   r2 = RandomReal[{1, Last@acc}];
   While[
    r1 > acc[[i]] || r2 > acc[[i]],
    If[r1 > acc[[i]], i1 = i];
    If[r2 > acc[[i]], i2 = i];
    i++;
    ];
   {i1, i2}
   ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed"}]
```

The surrounding code can be left mostly untouched:

```
m = 1;
w = ConstantArray[0, n] + m;
Table[{i, j} = randomChoice@Take[w, t];
 w[[{i, j}]]++; i <-> j, {t, 2, n}]
```

In the following graph the blue line is the simulation using `RandomChoice` and the orange line is the simulation using `randomChoice`. Because of the thing that I mentioned I believe that the difference is only going to grow as `n` grows. The data points are for `n = {10^3, 5 10^3, 10^4, 5 10^4, 10^5}`, the y axis is given in seconds.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A further optimization might be to not use `Accumulate` which will sum over all elements. Instead the total sum of vertex degrees can be calculated as `t (m + 2)` and the accumulated value can be calculated in the `While` loop.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think to look into how RandomChoice works and you're right, that is a much better way to go about it.